# Show that $k = 2$ (Use the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_n = 1$)

Tags: probability-theory

The set of numbers $p_1, p_2, p_3, ..., p_\infty$ such that $P(X = n) = p_n = \frac{k}{3^n}$ define an infinite probability space associated with the number of attempts, X needed to win the lottery.

$k$ is a constant.

Show that $k = 2$ (Use the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_n = 1$)

I just don't know how to approach this question.

Okay some thoughts. I'm not sure I fully understand the question.

$p_1 = \frac{k}{3}; p_2 = \frac{k}{3^2}; p_3 = \frac{k}{3^3}$

$p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + ... = 1$

$\frac{k}{3} + \frac{k}{3^2} + \frac{k}{3^3} + ... = 1$

$k (\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{3^3} + ... = 1$

$\frac{1}{k} = 3^{-1} + 3^{-2} + 3^{-3} + ...$

$r=\frac{1}{3}$

$\frac{1}{k} = \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}$

$\frac{1}{k}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$

$k = 2$

Oh I just worked it out. Sorry.

Comment: For the $n$th time, please indicate your thoughts. You MUST have some...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series

Comment: I apologize. Sometimes I post questions without thinking them through properly. I should stop doing that.

Comment: Is the working that I did in the question not sufficient?

Comment: "I post questions without thinking them through properly" Indeed, and this shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^n}=1$, which is pretty trivial:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^n}=2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n}=2\cdot\frac{1}{3-1}=1$$

Comment: Oh I just noticed you just worked it out. Sorry.

Comment: It's chilled. I appreciate the alternative approach. Also. I'm just wondering. Obviously if there were no attempts, there would be no chance of winning but if $n=0$, surely $p_0= \frac{2}{3^0} = 2$?

Comment: @StephanCasey: I was indeed wondering whether I should tell you to change that subscript in the title of your question from $\sum\limits_{n=0}$ to $\sum\limits_{n=1}$...

Comment: Oh okay. Good point. I'll do that.